# Node.js listen() throws 'EADDRINUSE' after server.close()

Tags: node.js

I am trying to terminate cluster workers when they are not needed to free up some resources. Here is the code I use in worker:

```
server.on("close", function() {
    process.exit();
});
server.close();
```

This code is executed when the worker gets the command from master. The "close" callback IS called, but I can't access any ports that the workers were using. So I have this code

```
var server = require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('');
});
server.listen(8080);
```

And if I restart the worker after it exits, I get 'EADDRINUSE' for the listen() on 8080 port.

Comment: Can you tell how you are stopping the node process ? `Ctrl+C` should not cause this problem. If it still exists, then try `fg`, it will bring background processes to front if any. This may help you.

Comment: @Pranav I am using the native cluster module to `fork()` and then within the worker I call `process.exit()`. The cluster master receives the `cluster.on('exit')` callback, so the process **is** stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Socket.io (what is getting listening on the port) is not releasing the port until it is terminated. It is done in order to allow port-reuse. I was able to re-create a socket.io instance using the exactly same port as was used before. So if I use port 8080 for socket.io connection to shopping cart and port 8081 for socket responsible for the recommendations, I would have to call `listen(8080)` the next time I create the shopping cart socket instance.

I wanted to use different ports for different connections at different times. I was trying to announce the connections as they were available, but I guess I will have to hardcode the ports for different services now. At least the EADDRINUSE does not show up any more.

Answer (score 1):

Please run this script  to kill node related process. and run your code again

```
(function(){
   "use strict";  
    var exec    = require('child_process').exec,
    lCmd    = 'kill -9'             +   ' ' + /* kill finded process */
              '`ps ax'              +   '|' + /* show all process    */
              'grep node-openshift' +   '|' + /* find node-openshift */
              'grep -v grep'        +   '|' + /* exlude grep command */
              'awk "{print $1}"`';            /* show first collumn  */

     exec(lCmd, function(error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log(error || stdout || stderr);
 }); 
})();
```

Comment: It would be easier if you use `pkill` instead. Your lCmd will then have a value of `pkill -9 -f node-openshift`. Simpler, isn't it?

Comment: `{ [Error: Command failed: kill: 1: Usage: kill [-s sigspec | -signum | -sigspec] [pid | job]... or kill -l [exitstatus]] killed: false, code: 2, signal: null }`
And wouldn't this kill the master?